# Mapping an array in PHP with this array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array as follows,

```
$arr['fixed_key'][0]['key1']['key2'] = 'y';
$arr['fixed_key'][1]['key1']['key2'] = 'y';
$arr['fixed_key'][2]['key1']['key2'] = 'n';
$arr['fixed_key'][3]['key1']['key2'] = 'n';
```

I want to remove all arrays which have key2='n', I can traverse through array in a loop and achieve this, as follows:

```
$l=length($arr);
for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++) {

    if($arr['fixed_key'][$i]['key1']['key2'] == 'n') {

        unset($arr['fixed_key'][$i]['key1']['key2']);

    }

}
```

My question is, is it possible to do this in better way, like array_map or array_walk, what is the best possible way?

Comment: you will do it with array_map and array_walk but you want to unset it in that functions also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_filter`

```
$arr['fixed_key'][0]['key1']['key2'] = 'y';
$arr['fixed_key'][1]['key1']['key2'] = 'y';
$arr['fixed_key'][2]['key1']['key2'] = 'n';
$arr['fixed_key'][3]['key1']['key2'] = 'n';

$filtered = array_filter($arr['fixed_key'], function ($val) { return $val['key1']['key2']  !== "n"; });
```

Answer (score 1):

We can achive by using array_search() and unset, try the following:

```
if(($key = array_search($del_value, $arr)) !== false) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
 }
```

Comment: Nope you can't this'll work single dimensional array and not for multidimensional array

Comment: @Uchiha You are right, besides that, we also don't wanna traverse in the inner dimensions unnecessarily. Nimshad Abdul's solution looks good. We can't use unset($arr) inside arrap_map function, so array_filter is the best choice to go to.